# How to join two ID's into a single column?

Tags: awk

I have three columns of ID's that are repeating combinations. How do I combine the first two columns so they become one unique ID? Example ID's:

```
0 F 2
1 D 3
2 K 4
3 O 5
```

Need it to look like:

```
0F 2
1D 3
2K 4
3O 5
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the entirety of the input? I mean is this all that is on each line and all that is in the file?

Comment: Does `tr -d ' ' < infile > outfile` suffice?

Comment: No. In reality I am dealing with joining a 15 digit alphanumeric id with a 4 digit numeric id. The file is about 300,000 lines. There are also other columns containing data.

Comment: @JustinBuchanan if you think pfnuesel's answer is correct, make sure to click the checkmark next to it and upvote it.

Comment: @nachocab I just hit the check, but I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation....I need to work on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed 's/ //' inputFile
```

or [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '{print $1$2" "$3}' inputFile
```

Comment: Or `awk '{print $1$2,$3}' file`